# Is it possible don't create a lot of variables of a struct for read and update the value inside?

Tags: swift, swiftui, viewmodel

I have a simple code for update an user in a viewModel but I want to Know if is it possible that I can use other way for show one or much properties of a struct and make changes without create new variables

This is my code...

```
struct UpdateEmployee: View {    

    @ObservedObject var employeesViewModel : EmployeesViewModel
    @Binding var employee: User
    @State var name = ""
    @State var correo = ""
    @State var genero = ""
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            VStack{
                Text("Nombre")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                 TextField("Nombre", text: $name)
                    .frame(maxHeight: 45)
                    .border(Color.gray, width: 0.5)
                    .padding([.horizontal, .bottom, .top], 30)
            }
            VStack{
                Text("Correo")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                TextField("Correo", text: $correo)
                    .frame(maxHeight: 45)
                    .border(Color.gray, width: 0.5)
                    .padding([.horizontal, .bottom, .top], 30)
            }
            VStack{
                Text("Genero")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                
                TextField("Genero", text: $genero)
                    .frame(maxHeight: 45)
                    .border(Color.gray, width: 0.5)
                    .padding([.horizontal, .bottom, .top], 30)
            }
            
            Button {
                print(employee.id)
                employee.name = name
                employee.email = correo
                employee.sex = genero
                employeesViewModel.updateEmployee(employee: employee)
            } label: {
                Text("Actualizar")
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .onAppear{
            self.name = employee.name ?? ""
            self.correo = employee.email ?? ""
            self.genero = employee.sex ?? ""
    
            
            
        }
        
    }

}
```

In this code I create variables name, email and sex, those are inside of struct User (employee), I like to know if it possible don't create the variables.

Comment: You have both a Binding to a User and a view model and some State properties for that User so it's hard to understand what the best solution is but one way is to work directly with the Binding property and ignore the State properties but the connection between the Binding and the ObservedObject properties is unknown

Comment: Why is unknown?

Comment: Because that code isn't part of the question, I meant unknown to us who reads your question not in some technical sense.